# Create a table inside the table(nested table) in mysql

Tags: mysql

I created a database named `resultsDB`. Inside the `resultsDB` is a table called `tblContinent`. Now I want to create another table inside the `tblContinent` called `tblAsia` and inside the `tblAsia` are columns such as `Philippines`,`Japan`,`Korea`, `Thailand` and so on. I'm trying to generate them in `phpmyadmin` but no luck. Is it possible what I want to do? Any suggestions?

Comment: MySql as a relational database cant have nested tables. This its a typical model for no-sql databases. Check @H. Mahida answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no concept of nested table in mysql.

But you can archive same things by settings relationships of parent child tables. I mean using primary key and foreign key.

**create : tblContinent**

```
  Id (PK)

  Name
```

**create : tblCountry**

```
 ID (PK)

 CID (foreign Key to tableContinent)

 Name
```

So, this way you will have list of all continent and the country in each continent.

Hope it helps..!!!!

Answer (score 3):

just an example to the @Mahida's sol:

```
 1. Parent table Automobile {Auto ID} 
     Child tables 
     1. Car {Auto ID,CarID}
     2. Truck {Auto ID,Trucks ID}
     3. Bus {Auto ID,BusID}
```

Here Auto ID column is a Primary key to Automobile table and foreign to Car,Truck,Bus tables. Hope you got what you need.